# Should I use the webpack command or the webpack-cli command?

Tags: node.js, webpack, command-line-interface, webpack-4, webpack-cli

I understand that the [webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack) package and the [webpack-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-cli) package both need to be installed in order to use webpack commands. I understand that in webpack 3 there was just one package and it contained the command line functionality, but in webpack 4 the command line functionality has been separated out into its own package. However, both `webpack` and `webpack-cli` work on the command line, and they seem to do the same thing. I tried looking into the source code a bit and the two commands eventually seem to call the same function, but they do it in two different roundabout ways rather than having one simply call the other or be an alias for the other. This makes me second guess myself.

I can't find any information online that compares these two commands. All the information I could find seems to be talking about the *packages* rather than the commands themselves, and it's easy to conflate the webpack-cli package with the idea of running webpack itself from the CLI. So which one should I use?

Comment: Many Developers will install webpack-cli

Comment: Implement them webpack and webpack-cli. Each function you see has different functionality for npm modules.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `node_modules\.bin\webpack build` or `npx webpack build`, you underlying call `node_modules\.bin\webpack-cli build` actually. If you don't install webpack-cli, you will find you can't execute `webpack xxx` command, and it will prompt you install the webpack-cli.